# The power of matrix in Maple over Galois Field

Tags: maple

How to compute the power of matrix in [Galois Field](https://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/maple/view.aspx?path=GF) in Maple. The [Using Packages](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=UsingPackages) is not applicable for calculation power of matrix in Galois Field.

For example, suppose that the $A$ is a matrix which entries come from GF($2^8$). Now I want to obtain, for instance, $A^{100}$ over  GF($2^8$).

I would be grateful for any suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Response of support team of Maple to this Question**

*You can try the "LinearAlgebra[Generic]" package, in conjunction with the "GF" package. Please try the following:*

restart;

with( LinearAlgebra[Generic] ):

f := alpha -> alpha^4 + alpha + 1;

G16 := GF( 2, 4, f(alpha) );

alias( phi = G16:-ConvertIn );

MatrixPower[G16] := proc( M :: Matrix, p :: nonnegint )

option remember:

local c, r, w:

r, c := LinearAlgebra:-Dimension( M );

if r <> c then error( "Matrix needs to be square." ) end if:

if p = 0 then return LinearAlgebra:-IdentityMatrix( r ) end if:

return simplify( M . MatrixPower[G16]( M, p-1 ) ):

end proc:

A := Matrix( [ [1,0,1], [2,1,0], [0,0,alpha] ] );

B := phi~(A);

MatrixMatrixMultiply[G16]( B, B );

MatrixInverseG16;

MatrixPower[G16]( A, 3 );

Thanks again from support team of Maple for this useful answer.